# Is $f(\overline{x})=\overline{x-3}$ is one-to-one if $f:\mathbb{Z}_{10}\to\mathbb{Z}_{10}$? Prove why?

Tags: analysis, logic, modular-arithmetic

Prove $f(\overline{x})=\overline{x-3}$ is one-to-one if $f:\mathbb{Z}_{10}\to\mathbb{Z}_{10}$?

Using different values, I'm sure it's one-to-one but I'm unsure how to prove this?

I know to start with $\overline{x_1-3}=\overline{x_2-3}$. Since, $x_1-3=z\!\!\!\mod\!\!{10}$ and $x_2-3=z\!\!\!\mod\!\!{10}$. Modular addition is well-defined, meaning $\overline{x_1}-\overline{3}=\overline{x_2}-\overline{3}$ and $\overline{x_1}=\overline{x_2}$.

However, I'm unsure how credible this method is? I found if $f(\overline{x})=\overline{2x+1}$, then f is not one-to-one. How do we show mathematically (without examples) that this is the case?

Comment: What does overline mean?  Is it method of distinguishing equivalence classes of $Z_{10}$ from the integers?

Comment: Yes, it establishes equivalence classes; however, my question was answered? Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider $f(x)= \overline{x-3}$,

If $\overline{x_1-3}=\overline{x_2-3}$, then we have
$$\overline{x_1-3}+\overline{3}=\overline{x_2-3}+\overline{3}$$

$$\overline{x_1}=\overline{x_2}$$

---

Now in contrast, if we define $g(x)=\overline{2x+1}$,

If we have $$\overline{2x_1+1}=\overline{2x_2+1}$$

then we have $$\overline{2x_1}=\overline{2x_2}$$

and we can't multiply it by $2^{-1}$ since $\gcd(2,10)\ne 1$.  Let's show that it is not one-to-one. Let $x_1=\overline{0}$ and $x_2=\overline{5}$, then we have $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$ even though $x_1 \ne x_2$.